# NodeJs Try to evaluate a HTML Form

Tags: html, node.js, express

I've an problem with evaluating an HTML Form using NodeJs and express.

This is my Java Script Code

My goal is to handle  HTML Form in nodeJs using express.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

var warehouses = [];

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

  app.use("/warehouse", (req, res, next) => {
    fs.readFile("./addWarehouse.html", function(err, data) {

    res.write(data);
    next();

    });

  });



  app.post("/warehouse/add", (req, res) => {


    console.log("ADDED");

    // warehouses.push(req.body.nWarehouse);
    console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
    res.end;
  });

app.listen(8080);
```

And this is my HTML Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Coole Seite</title>

</head> -->
<body>
    <h1>Warehouses</h1>

    <form method='POST' action="/warehouse/add">
        <input type="text" name="nWarehouse"  id="nWarehouse"/>
        <input typse="submit" value="bitte sende" />
     </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to debug it with the console output and I figured out that it never access the app.use("/submit/add/" ... " part.

I would be happy to get some advice.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using app.use(...) instead app.post(...)? You may want to change that and try again.

Comment: I tried but it also failed with app.post()

Comment: you need to add `app.listen(port)` right now your express server is not listening to any port, after that you should correct the route to be `app.post` as well unless you want this function to act as a middleware.

Comment: First of all Thank you Tom.

I edited my Code, but it still don't work.@tom

Comment: @tomslabbaert `http.createServer(app).listen(8080);` this is fine because [`app.listen(port)`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) although handy is just a wrapper for that. @Alex the request never reaches `/submit/add` because you end the request `res.end()` at the middleware `app.use("/submit", ...)`

Comment: you're listening for `/submit` on the server but POSTing to `/submit/add` in the client.

Comment: @ambianBeing  Thank you, I fixed it.
DanO I thought It work like I send it to /sumbit/add and receive in the /submit/add part .

Comment: @ambianBeing now I end it in the app.post part is this correct? It still don't go inside this part.

Comment: @ambianBeing now I get the following error Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:232:21)
    at /Users/alexanderhess/Desktop/SEP/Workshops/APS-Workshop/NodeJs/myfirst.js:13:9
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

Comment: @Alex Now you've change the routes mounting as well but the form is still going to do post to `/submit`. The reason u're getting this error because of `res.writeHead` and `res.write` you cannot send back request twice isn't it.. first at middleware second at route controller. What is it that you want to achieve with that middleware anyways & in general, update that in question to get better help and visiblity.

Comment: @ambianBeing sorry I didn't update the html code here. I just want to achieve to handle an html form with express. 

This means that I online use res.write or res.writeHead?

Comment: @Alex If I get the requirement right, there isn't a need to use a **middleware** for the purpose, and you might've understood the use-case of it wrong. Have updated the code in the answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here if the intent is to evaluate the form that is there in **`addWarehouse.html`** which should render when you go to **`/warehouse`** and the form should submit to **`/warehouse/add`**.

*The middleware concept used via `app.use(...)` here is not required at all.*

**Express code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

var warehouses = [];

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//show addWareHouse.html for /warehouse
/* serving the HTML via fs */
app.get("/warehouse", (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile("./addWarehouse.html", function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });

//add warehouse form submit for /warehouse/add
app.post("/warehouse/add", (req, res) => {
  console.log("ADDED");
  console.log("REQUEST PARAM::", req.body);
  //do you adding of ware-house stuff here
  console.log("Request Type:", req.method);
  return res.end();
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`app listening on port 8080!`));
```

**Note:**
There are other handy ways to serve views (HTML) in express like template engines, `res.sendFile()` etc.